# How can I promisify an AJAX request onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, es6-promise

I'm making a javascript AJAX request, if I am using the classic `callback`, I am able to to call the callback on the `onreadystatechange` function and it's returning all the `readyState` value.

I tried changing my `callback` functions to promises. When I resolved on the `onreadystatechange` function, I notice it's only returned the first `readyState` value which is 2, instead of 2,3 and 4.

```
_.request = async (headers, path, method, queryObj, payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    path =  (typeof path == 'string') ? path : '/';
    queryObj =  (typeof queryObj == 'object' && queryObj !== null) ? queryObj : {};
    method = (typeof method == 'string' && ['POST','PUT','DELETE','GET'].indexOf(method.toUpperCase()) > -1) ? method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';
    headers = (typeof headers == 'object' && headers !== null) ? headers : {};
    payload = (typeof payload == 'object' && payload !== null) ? payload : {};

    let requestUrl = path + '?';
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i in queryObj) {
      if (queryObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        counter++
        if (counter > 1) {
          requestUrl += '&';
        }
        requestUrl += i + '=' + queryObj[i];
      }
    }
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, requestUrl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    for (let i in headers) {
      if (headers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(i, headers[i]);
      }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      const response = {
        rs: xhr.readyState,
        sc: xhr.status,
        re: xhr.responseText
      };
      try {
        response.re = JSON.parse(response.re);
        resolve(response);
      } catch {
        resolve(response);
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).on('ready', async (e) => {
  const data = await _.request(undefined, '/views/getarticle', 'get', undefined, undefined);
  console.log(data); // readyState: 2
});
```

I expected it returned all the `readyState` values. If my approach won't work, is there any possible way to do this without using `callback`?

Comment: A promise can only ever be resolved ONCE.  It's a one-shot device.  It changes from pending to resolved or pending to rejected and can never change after that. 
 Also, your code doesn't show how you're wrapping this in a `new Promise()` and doesn't show how you want to use it to know what to suggest instead.

Comment: I just updated it, if have any other way to do this, it'll be hugely appreciated! I will give more additional information if needed.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  You already have `.onreadystatechange` as an event handler that gets called for each state change.  Promises are not an appropriate tool for something meant to fire more than once.  Perhaps either an eventEmitter or just a plain callback is the right tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to listen/fetch value from multiple event which is generated by onreadystatechange method. For this promise is not very helpfull. if you want to get value from multiple event. you can use observable from rxjs library or you can use event listener in nodejs.